# To check whether thread's apartment type is MTA or STA?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

Is there any way so that i can check the apartment type of thread,whether it is MTA or STA while debugging an application on runtime ? I am working on winforms application in visual studio 2008 IDE.

Comment: `thread.GetApartmentState()` ?

Comment: Any way to check the same on runtime without writing this code ??

Comment: @Mandar You can assign the result of `GetAparmentState()` to a variable somewhere in your thread, and check its value with the debugger

Comment: Do the same in debugger in "immediate window".

Comment: Ok thnx for the help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Thread.GetApartmentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to get ApartmentState of the current thread. This method will return you `ApartmentState` Enumeration that has values `STA`, `MTA` and `Unknown`

If you want to set the ApartmentState you can use [Thread.SetApartmentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please note that this property is **obsolete**. You should use the proper methods: `GetApartmentState()` and `SetApartmentState()`